# Why is the default nont-trivial move constructor of unions in C++ std::memmove?

Tags: c++

Say the union holds a class type with non-trivial move constructor, like `std::shared_ptr` (or `std::string` ?). Now one moves this union to another union using `std::move`. When the source object gets out of scope, it will be destructed, right? However if it was not set to an `empy' state when moved, it may free resources in its destructor that should actually belong to the new location. Isn't this behavior dangerous? - Especially since the default non-trivial move constructor of class / struct types is different since it does a member-wise move, allowing the members to clean the source objects.

Comment: *"it will be destructed, right"* You need to write a destructor for the union, otherwise it will not compile. Since the compiler has no way to know what field is acitve, in that destructor, you need to manually destroy `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why do you think the default move constructor of a union does `memmove()`? It seems it doesn't exist by default.

Comment: See [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) paragraph _Implicitly-declared move constructor_ - maybe I got it wrong?

Comment: @erbth Further below there is "**Deleted** implicitly-declared move constructor". Your union probably  qualifies for "T is a union-like class and has a **variant member with non-trivial move constructor"**.

Comment: @erbth: I don't see where `memmove` fits into this question. Nowhere in the standard does it say that `memmove` will be called for such a union.

Comment: @NicolBolas Same page: " For union types, the implicitly-defined move constructor copies the object representation (as by std::memmove)". It's not the standard though, granted.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but since we're specifically talking about a case where the `union` "holds a class type with non-trivial move constructor", that line is irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica true, but deleted means defined but deleted. I think setting it to `= default` will enable it.

Comment: @erbth [Tried it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/157aa2bb85b6472b), it still ends up deleted.

Comment: @NicolBolas didn't try (just reading documentation) but I think this may hold for default constructors, too.

Comment: @erbth: What "may hold for default constructors"? That the union will have a deleted implicit default constructor if any member of the union has a non-trivial default constructor? That's true, and it's stated in the documentation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see. Well, didn't know that `= default` qualifies for _implicitly created_, too. Thought it would be like forced-by-user or something.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica then you're right, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `union` type which holds a member whose move constructor is non-trivial will have a deleted implicit move constructor. Furthermore, attempting to `= default` the move constructor will [*also* make it deleted](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#10). Essentially, there can be no valid movement default behavior for such a type.

Therefore, if we have a `union` that has a member with a non-trivial move constructor, and you are able to legally move-construct one, then there *must* be a user-defined move constructor on that `union`. And therefore, it is the user's responsibility to make sure that the move constructor does the right thing for the currently active member.

Answer (score 2):

A move constructor or move assignment operator is *required* to leave the moved from object in a unknown (unless documented), valid and destructible state. If that is not done then the move constructor/operator is simply broken.

If you move from an object and it's move constructor leaves the moved-from object in a state where deleting it would result in double delete of resources or similar, then whomever implemented the move constructor/operator didn't do the job properly.

Comment: *required* by whom? Does the standard have any such statement for user-defined types?

Comment: @Ayxan http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#:Cpp17MoveAssignable - I trust you can find the rest yourself by searching [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/), but the previous link should be enough to prove what I said.

Comment: True but what if it is implicitely generated by the compiler? Without A(A&&) = default?

Comment: @erbth: `union`s [don't implicitly generate move constructors if they hold non-trivial types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). So your question is moot.